# return all machine network interfaces collection

Tags: c#

this is my class that i want to return my machine network interfaces collection.
i choose to return IEnumerable and i dont know how to do it (i am a new developer).
or maybee there is batter way to build my class ?

```
public class NetworkAdapter
{
    string _name;
    string _id;        
    string _description;
    string _ipAddress;
    string _gatewayIpAddress;
    string _speed;
    string _networkInterfaceType;
    string _macAddress;

    public IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> getAdapterInfo()
    {
        foreach (var adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            //fetch network configuration properties
            var properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            foreach (var uniCast in properties.UnicastAddresses)
            {
                //ignore loop-back addresses & IPv6 internet protocol family
                if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) 
                    && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) 
                {
                    _name = adapter.Name;
                    _id = adapter.Id;
                    _description = adapter.Description;
                    _ipAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString();
                    _networkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString();
                    _speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0");

                    _macAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();

                    var gatewayAddresses = adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses;
                    foreach (var gatewayAddress in gatewayAddresses)
                    {
                        _gatewayIpAddress = gatewayAddress.Address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        yield return new NetworkAdapter att;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use linq:

```
return from adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
       from uniCast in adapter.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses
       where !IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6
       let lastGatewayAddress = adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.LastOrDefault()
       select new NetworkAdapter
       {
           _name = adapter.Name,
           _id = adapter.Id,
           _description = adapter.Description,
           _ipAddress = uniCast.Address.ToString(),
           _networkInterfaceType = adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString(),
           _speed = adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0"),
           _macAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString(),
           _gatewayIpAddress = lastGatewayAddress == null ? null : lastGatewayAddress.Address.ToString()
       };
```

It's not clear what you're trying to do with the gateway addresses. At the moment it looks like you want the last one, although you might want to join them into a single string instead. In that case you can use:

```
_gatewayIpAddress = string.Join(" ", adapater.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.Select(a => a.Address));
```

Comment: where i need to put _gatewayIpAddress = string.Join(" ", adapater.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses); ?

Comment: @user1710944 - You'd use it instead of `_gatewayIpAddress = lastGatewayAddress == null ? null : lastGatewayAddress.ToString()`. It depends on what you want the `gatewayIpAddresses` string to look like.

Comment: the default gateway empty in the first adapter and in the second it just System.Net.NetworkInformation.SystemGatewayIPAddressInformation

Comment: @user1710944 - I missed the `Address` property for the gateway addresses

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object of `NetworkAdapter` and use that `object` in `yield` return. I changed the private members to public to make them accessible to consumer class.

```
public class NetworkAdapter
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id  {get; set;}        
    public string Description  {get; set;}
    public string IpAddress  {get; set;}
    public string GatewayIpAddress  {get; set;}
    public string Speed  {get; set;}
    public string NetworkInterfaceType  {get; set;}
    public string MacAddress  {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> getAdapterInfo()
    {
        NetworkAdapter na = null;
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties(); //fetch network configuration properties
            foreach (IPAddressInformation uniCast in properties.UnicastAddresses)
            {
                if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) && uniCast.Address.AddressFamily != AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6) //ignore loop-back addresses & IPv6 internet protocol family
                {
                    na = new NetworkAdapter{ 
                    Name = adapter.Name;
                    Id= adapter.Id;
                    Description= adapter.Description;
                    IpAddress= uniCast.Address.ToString();
                    GatewayIpAddress= adapter.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString();
                    Speed= adapter.Speed.ToString("#,##0");

                    NetworkInterfaceType = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                    };

                    foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation gatewayAddress in adapter.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
                    {
                        na.GatewayIpAddress = gatewayAddress.Address.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
             yield return na ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't have all the interface properties here

Comment: why it's return only the first adapter and skip the second ?

Comment: Comment this condition and check if you get more adaptor, //if (!IPAddress.IsLoopback(uniCast.Address) &&...

Comment: The yield return is outside foreach loop thats is way you would be getting one, I updated my answer and put it inside foreach give it a try.

Comment: it's strange because now it returns the same adapter twice

Comment: You need to debug, I think its not going in inner foreach loop. you can try putting yield return in inner loop